# Error : Index was outside the bounds of the array, String array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

After trying a few error checking methods I have come to the conclusion I need help solving this problem.
How am I not catch this "index out of range" error and what can i do to avoid this problem in the future.

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();
string[] nums = line.Split(); 
int m = Convert.ToInt32(nums[0]);
int n = Convert.ToInt32(nums[1]);
int k = Convert.ToInt32(nums[2]);
int[,] a = new int[m, n];
Input(a); 
static void Input(int[,] a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        string[] nums = Console.ReadLine().Split();
        {
            for (int j = 0; i < a.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                a[i, j] = int.Parse(nums[j]); // where i get the problem //
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're getting an `IndexOutOfRangeException` but you haven't told us what the index is or the range, which suggests that you haven't actually determined that for yourself. You need to debug your code first.

Comment: Classic C&P Error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int j = 0; i < a.GetLength(1); j++)
```

Look *very carefully* at that line. One of these things is not like the others.